# How does the Apache download for Windows work?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I'm looking at the [Apache download](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) site and I can't see the Windows download (MSI installer) for Apache 2.2 or 2.4. There is only the UNIX source and NetWare Binary. I thought a I had installed 2.2.22 on a Windows machine using an installer in the past. Looking at the [Other Files link](http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache//httpd/), there is a Win32 source zip but no MSI installer.

So the question is how does the distribution work? Do the Windows versions go offline after some time?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I thought it was a valid question to see if there is a distribution procedure that would explain this.

Comment: not to be too harsh, but Server Fault is not the place to be asking "where can I get `some piece of software`?" -- that's what Google is for. If you google "Apache download Windows" (or click "Other files" -> "binaries" -> "win32" on the Apache download page) you'll find the MSI files you're looking for -- the latest official builds from the Apache project. The second part of your question - "How does the distribution process for Apache work?" - is really a question for the ASF, not us...

Comment: @voretaq7 its quite evident from the answer that the problem is not that straightforward that we can simply "google" and get the answer. in fact, i "googled" and came to this page. +1 for the question and the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://apache.hippo.nl//httpd/binaries/win32/) are some Wind32 builds on the download site, including the 2.2.22 you mention.

It appears that version 2.4 does not come with Windows builds for now. See the [comments section of the Windows notes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#comments_section)

Comment: Thanks, is there a Win32 for 2.2.23?

Comment: As you can see yourself, no. You'll have to build it yourself, I guess. 2.2.22 comes with [some security issues](http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_22.html), so I can't recommend this for production usage unless you understand and work around these.

Comment: Also consider using these community builds (potentially unsafe, because unofficial) [at apachelounge.com](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/).